# Problem with comparing 2 DataFrames in Python, should exclude all duplicates, but works unproperly

Tags: python, sql, pandas, duplicates, google-analytics-api

I'm developing a connector Google Analytics to SQL Server database and have a problem with duplicate values.

First, the script parses a nested dict with GA Accounts config, then converts it to pandas df and stores all responses in a list, after that a current SQL table with all GA Data is fetched and a loop comparing new values (from GA API) and current values (in sql table) is made.

But for some reason when comparing these 2 dfs all duplicates are preserved.

I would be really happy if someone could help.

A nested dict with config for making a GA API request

```py
data_test = {
    
    'view_id_111' : {'view_id': '111', 
                           'start_date': '2019-08-01', 
                           'end_date': '2019-09-01',
                           'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expression':'ga:users'}],
                           'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}, {'name': 'ga:userType'}, {'name': 'ga:date'}]},
    
     'view_id_222' : {'view_id': '222', 
                           'start_date': '2019-08-01', 
                           'end_date': '2019-09-01',
                           'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expression':'ga:users'}],
                           'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}, {'name': 'ga:date'}]},
    
    'view_id_333' : {'view_id': '333', 
                           'start_date': '2019-01-01', 
                           'end_date': '2019-05-01',
                           'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expression':'ga:users'}],
                           'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}, {'name': 'ga:date'}]} 
}
```

1. Send request to Google API, convert it to df and store values in a list

```py
responses = []

for k, v in data_test.items():
    
    sample_request = {
        'viewId': v['view_id'],
        'dateRanges': {
            'startDate': v['start_date'],
            'endDate': v['end_date']
        },
        'metrics': v['metrics'],
        'dimensions': v['dimensions']
    }
    
    response = analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            'reportRequests': sample_request
        }).execute()
    
    n_response=print_response_new_test(response)
    responses.append(n_response)
```

2. Fetch current SQL table with GA data

```py
def get_current_sql_gadata_table():
    global sql_table_current_gadata
    sql_table_current_gadata = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM Table', con=conn)
    sql_table_current_gadata['date'] = pd.to_datetime(sql_table_current_gadata['date'])
    return sql_table_current_gadata
```

3. Finally compare 2 DFs and if there are any differences between, update the SQL table

```py
def compare_df_gadata():
    
    for report in responses:
        response=pd.DataFrame.equals(sql_table_current_gadata, report)
        if response==False:
            compared_dfs = pd.concat([sql_table_current_gadata, report], sort=False)
            compared_dfs.drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=True)
    
            #sql params in sqlalchemy
            params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(#params)
            engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params))

            #insert new values to the sql table
            compared_dfs.to_sql('Table', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I've tried also merging 2 tables, but the result is the same. Maybe it's more reasonable to make a check-in MS Studio?

Doesn't work properly also

```
df_outer = pd.merge(sql_table_current_gadata, report, on=None, how='left', sort=True)
```

## UPDATE

I checked another time with concat function and it looks like the problem is in 'index'.

The original 240 rows (960 were already with duplicates, so just cleaned SQL table and run the script again).

I have 3 GA accounts from which the current SQL table consists: 72 rows + 13 rows  + 154 rows  + header = 240 rows.

And when running the script again, comparing with pd.concat and storing the result in a dataframe (compared_dfs) (not sending it to the database), it contains the 154 rows from the last request to GA API.

I tried to reset here:

```
if response==False:
            compared_dfs = pd.concat([sql_table_current_gadata, report], sort=False)
            compared_dfs.drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=True)
            compared_dfs.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

But as a result it was added as an additional column in a compared_dfs

[Resulted DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXY43.png)

It shows 2 index columns, one from the SQL table and another from pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is detailed but quite articulated to follow. I would first ask if you are sure about your indexes, could you try merge on specific columns to see if this solves the problem?
I'm focusing on the pandas part first as it seems the focus of your question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

merge = True
concat = False

anp = np.ones((2, 5))
anp[1, 1] = 3
anp[1, 4] = 3
bnp = np.ones((1, 5))
bnp[0, 1] = 4  # use 4 to make it different, also works with nan
bnp[0, 4] = 4  # use 4 to make it different, also works with nan
a = pd.DataFrame(anp)
b = pd.DataFrame(bnp)
if merge:
    a.rename(columns=dict(zip(range(5), ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])), inplace=True)
    b.rename(columns=dict(zip(range(5), ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])), inplace=True)
    # choose suitable and meaningful column(s) for your merge (do you have any id column etc.?)
    a = pd.merge(a, b, how='outer', copy=False, on=['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
    # che
    print(a)

if concat:
    # can use ignore_index or pass keys to maintain distiction
    c = pd.concat((a, b), axis=0, join='outer', keys=['a', 'b'])
    print(c)
    c.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    print(c)
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for my problem expression. I've tried to merge on 'view_id' column, but it multiplies everything from 960 original rows and 35 columns  to 23716 rows × 41 columns. It doubles the columns which are indicated in the API requst like dimenstions, metrics, start date and end date.

the code:         

                       
```lang-py
for report in responses:
    df_outer = pd.merge(report, test, on='view_id', how='left', sort=False)
```

Comment: I checked another time with concat function and it looks like the problem is in 'index'. 

The original 240 rows (960 were already with duplicates, so just cleaned sql table and run the script again). I have 3 GA accounts: 72 rows + 13 rows  + 154 rows  + header = 240 rows. And when running the script again, comparing with pd.concat and stroring the result in a dataframe, it contains the 154 rows from the last request to GA API.

Comment: good, once the indexes are well set you should be able to obtain what you need, alternatively I updated my answer with an example based on columns. This seems quite explicit to me, and suited for fixed tables as in your case, other solutions are likely more upscalable and flexible, for example using drop_duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I tried with the data but it crashes idk why on one of the columns :( (below is more detailed info)

Comment: I updated the answer. I thought your tables were much smaller and simpler, so that you could have more control on the possible values. Anyway, I think what you want to do can be done with both 1) concat() followed by drop_duplicates() and merge(). I think it doesn't make sense to guess what else your tables may hide, as said the whole implementation is long. So, try to build on one of the two possibilities and let me know if you have specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

Checking Luca Peruzzo solution, but it crashes if a column is empty

Get list of columns from the current sql table

```
list_of_col = list(sql_table_current_gadata.columns)
```

Iterate over reports from list of responses (GA API responses)

```
for report in responses:
    df_outer = pd.merge(test, report, how='outer', copy=False, on=list_of_col)
```

Throws an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-321-4fbfe59db175> in <module>
      1 for report in responses:
----> 2     df_outer = pd.merge(test, report, how='outer', copy=False, on=list_of_col)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     45                          right_index=right_index, sort=sort, suffixes=suffixes,
     46                          copy=copy, indicator=indicator,
---> 47                          validate=validate)
     48     return op.get_result()
     49 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    527         (self.left_join_keys,
    528          self.right_join_keys,
--> 529          self.join_names) = self._get_merge_keys()
    530 
    531         # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_merge_keys(self)
    831                         if rk is not None:
    832                             right_keys.append(
--> 833                                 right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
    834                         else:
    835                             # work-around for merge_asof(right_index=True)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1704             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1705         else:
-> 1706             raise KeyError(key)
   1707 
   1708         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'userGender'
```

The list_of_col consists:

```
['view_id',
 'start_date',
 'end_date',
 'userType',
 'userGender',
 'userAgeBracket',
 'sourceMedium',
 'source',
 'socialNetwork',
 'region',
 'regionId',
 'pageTitle',
 'pagePath',
 'pageDepth',
 'operatingSystemVersion',
 'operatingSystem',
 'mobileDeviceModel',
 'mobileDeviceMarketingName',
 'mobileDeviceInfo',
 'mobileDeviceBranding',
 'medium',
 'deviceCategory',
 'dataSource',
 'country',
 'continent',
 'continentId',
 'cityId',
 'city',
 'users',
 'sessions',
 'sessionDuration',
 'pageviews',
 'newUsers',
 'bounces',
 'date']
```

Also I checked 'userGender' has None values and it crashes on all empty columns